# NICE Properties of Auxiliary Verbs

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

### BACKGROUND

According to this ThoughtCo. article titled "[NICE Properties of Auxiliary Verbs](https://www.thoughtco.com/nice-properties-verbs-1691346)":

> *NICE* is an acronym for the four syntactic characteristics that distinguish **auxiliary verbs** from lexical verbs in English grammar: **n**egation, **i**nversion, **c**ode, **e**mphasis.
>
> The NICE properties were identified as such by linguist Rodney Huddleston in the article "Some Theoretical Issues in the Description of the English Verb" (*Lingua*, 1976).

I won't be explaining in detail what the NICE properties are, because they're fairly straightforward. If you're not familiar with them, please visit the link above for reference.

Here are some NICE property examples shown in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (page 93):

[image]

---

### QUESTIONS

In the above examples, only **finite** auxiliary verbs are shown to have the NICE properties. Do **non-finite** auxiliary verbs too have the NICE properties? If the NICE properties are "the four syntactic characteristics that distinguish auxiliary verbs from lexical verbs in English grammar", I think **non-finite** auxiliary verbs (as well as **finite** auxiliary verbs) should have the NICE properties. But they don't seem to.

Here are my failed attempts at producing NICE property examples of **non-finite** auxiliary verbs:

(1) *Not **having** seen it, he had no clue.* [Negation]

(2) N/A [Inversion]

(3) *He may **have** seen it and I may **have**.* [Code]

(4) ??*They don't think he **has** seen it but he must **HAVE** seen it.* [Emphasis]

In (1), *not* **typically** comes before *having* rather than *after*. It's not clear whether the *not* coming before *having* should be considered as negation of *having*. But let's assume for the moment that it should. Also, some speakers might put *not* after *having*, in which case *not* does negate *having*. It's possible, therefore, to argue that the non-finite auxiliary *having* does have the Negation property.

I can't think of any examples for (2) because there's no subject-auxiliary inversion in non-finite clauses.

In (3), although some speakers may choose to omit the second *have*, at least for those speakers who allow the second *have*, it can be said that the second *have*, a non-finite auxiliary, has the Code property.

In (4), it's unlikely that you could pronounce *HAVE* emphatically.

All in all, however hard I try, non-finite auxiliaries cannot seem to allow the Inversion and Emphasis constructions, which means that non-finite auxiliaries don't seem to have the NICE properties.

If **non-finite** auxiliary verbs don't have the NICE properties, which they don't seem to, is it really correct to say that the NICE properties are "the four syntactic characteristics that distinguish auxiliary verbs from lexical verbs in English grammar"?

Comment: You'd probably get more response if you added examples. And one can foresee the simple addition of a  'other than when used in non-finite clauses' caveat rectifying any potential problem. _All useful laws in English, except this one, have exceptions_.

Comment: @JK2 I agree with Edwin Ashworth: the thrust is that it would be extremely useful for you to give examples of *auxiliary verbs in non-finite clauses*

Comment: @Greybeard I don't think either Edwin or you (or anyone who's competent enough to answer the question, for that matter) don't fully understand the question for the lack of examples. But I'll edit the question to include some.

Comment: Isn't negation the only operation that can apply? 'Not having given it much thought, I can't really say' ≈ 'Not considering it a real problem, Huddleston didn't address it.' It's hardly comparable to 'I did not' vs *'I slept not', other than illustrating the fact that auxiliaries team up with main verbs to facilitate ways we say things, in ways main verbs don't.

Comment: You mean in examples like "[**Having** read the report], I can see what you mean" / "Ed was believed [to **have** been abroad at the time]." / "I find "[**being** nice to Kim] very difficult".?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the finite clause, _not_ comes after the auxiliary or forms a contraction with it. So, does _Not_ coming **before** _having_ in your example count as proper negation of the non-finite auxiliary _having_? I have edited to include some examples.

Comment: Yes, I thought for a moment you were saying that 1a (not 1) was non-finite.

Comment: You can say *Having not seen it, he had no clue.* Your code example has two auxiliaries, so that confounds the issue.

Comment: @TinfoilHat But I think the default position of _not_ is before _having_. As for my code example having two auxiliaries, I can't think of a code example having only one auxiliary.

Comment: Your wrong example is itself wrong; it must instead be *“He saw it **not**”*. Think of the old children’s rhyme intoned while plucking off the petals of a daisy one by one: *“She loves me, she loves me **not**; she loves me, she loves me **not**.”* This demonstrates how, especially poetically or archaically, the postposed negative ***always follows*** the object; it interposes itself **never** between the verb and its object. This then is why your wrong example is wrong: not for its mere post-positioning of the negative, but rather for its syntactically forbidden interposition of same.

Comment: @tchrist First, it's not my example. It's CGEL's example. Second, just because you can say _she loves me not_ doesn't mean you can also say _He saw it not_ in Present-day English. So I don't get your point.

Answer (score 5):

From a syntactic point of view, **auxiliary verbs** are **verbs** in that they conjugate (*I am, he has, she did*) and mark tense when necessary (i.e, in tensed clauses where they appear first), and **auxiliaries** because they have no intrinsic meaning except to mark constructions like  Passive,  Progressive, or Predicate Nouns; and they appear wherever they are required by some rule or construction and not elsewhere.

> (Syntacticians say auxiliaries are "inserted" by the rule or construction, but what we really mean is they're necessary to the machinery, like the dummy *it* in Extraposition, or the *to* on most infinitives.)

The property of "Negation" appears to mean that some kinds of negation require an auxiliary verb (which is usually contracted, with the negative or with a subject NP).

- *Bill is/isn't tired. ~ Bill has/hasn't left. ~ Bill must not have left*.
  (with auxiliaries already)
- *Bill likes cilantro*, but **Bill not likes/likes not cilantro*
  (without auxiliaries, so negation not grammatical)
- *Bill does not (doesn't) like cilantro*
  (with *Do*-support when there isn't an auxiliary to hand)

That's a property of negation of a particular sort, with *not* directly before the verb chain. Other types of negation don't require auxiliary verbs; it's only this one type of negation. So it's not really a property of auxiliary verbs, it's just another rule-based use for them.

- *Bill dislikes cilantro ~ Nobody in my family likes cilantro.*

"Inversion" is a property of the rule of Question Formation. Forming a question in English usually involves inversion of the subject and the first auxiliary, and thus requires an auxiliary verb. Again, if there is none, *do* is supplied. But this only works for questions, and only when they're not embedded -- complement questions are not inverted.

- *Bill works for Boeing ~ Why does Bill work for Boeing?*
- *I wonder why Bill works for Boeing,* but not **I wonder why does Bill work for Boeing?*

So "Inversion" is another use for auxiliary verbs, not a property. The property is associated with the rule that determines it, in this case, question formation.

"Code" appears to refer to deletion rules, like Conjunction Reduction. Again, this is a property of the rules governing the deletions, rather than auxiliary verbs themselves. The point here is that the first auxiliary verb in a clause can represent the entire verb phrase (and the entire clause when untensed) in sentences where deletion rules have occurred.

I would prefer a term like "pro-verb" for this, as *pronoun* parallels *noun*. That's what it's doing, and the term "Code" is not a helpful mnemonic -- EVERYTHING in language can be (and has been) called a *code*.

Finally, "Emphasis" is related to the pro-verbal use of auxiliaries. They can be stressed, effectively reduplicating the verb. Of course, this is not true just of auxiliaries. Any verb can be stressed, and stressing auxiliaries adds to the effect. So, yes, it's another use for auxiliary verbs; they do have a lot of uses, just like prepositions and pronouns and other nuts and bolts.

But they're all handled by the rule machinery.

Comment: You say, "From a syntactic point of view, auxiliary verbs are verbs in that they conjugate (_I am, he has, she did_) and mark tense when necessary (i.e, in tensed clauses where they appear first)...", but the same can be said about lexical verbs: they conjugate (_I live, he lives, she lived_) and mark tense when necessary (i.e, in tensed clauses where they appear first). Moreover, auxiliaries don't have to conjugate or mark tense (_I'll **be** there, he'll **have** finished it by now_).

Comment: Well, yes, of course. Those are properties of verbs, which makes them verbs (there's a long-standing argument about whether _be_ should be called a "verb" or not; I think it should, for these reasons). Following those properties of verbs that apply to them, I listed properties that are unique to **auxiliary** verbs, as a specialized (and rapidly changing) subset in wide use. Sorry to confuse you. I probly should have used more boldface to contrast them, or something. Oh, and I said _they conjugate_, not _they always conjugate_. They conjugate when they're sposta; they're verbs.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, if the NICE properties are not the unique properties of auxiliaries, as you suggest, the other syntactic properties that you have suggested as those of auxiliaries are also not the unique properties of auxiliaries.

Comment: The syntactic properties of auxiliaries are the ones I suggested, and they don't have anything to do with the "NICE properties". I was just trying to figure out what they were supposed to mean, since the description is unclear and abbreviated and there were few examples. So the "if the NICE properties are not unique..." clause has no conclusion. I'm just discussing auxiliary verbs in the light of what I can figure out about your question. I haven't even gotten to untensed clauses yet, and I may not.

Comment: I didn't say your syntactic properties of auxiliaries have anything to do with the NICE properties. All I'm saying is, they are no more unique to auxiliaries than are the NICE properties. Now, I'm surprised you find it hard to figure out what the NICE properties are supposed to mean. It's simply an acronym of the four characteristics of auxiliaries, each of which you must already be familiar with. Just in case you somehow are not, the ThoughtCo. article cited in OP has plenty of examples. And there's Google Scholar, if that's not enough.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with them as a package deal with brand names; I prefer product to advertising. And I want to look at the list of ingredients and see what's left out. Why is it suddenly difficult to identify English auxiliary verbs? Thousands of careful analyses of them exist, and certainly a brand established in 1976 should by now have become popular enough that it would be familiar in our mouths as household words. But NICE rings no bell, sorry. Auxiliary verbs are a solved problem.

Comment: I should add that I decided not to read the linked article after seeing the first sentence, which makes all kinds of advertising claims: _NICE is an acronym for **the four** syntactic characteristics that distinguish auxiliary verbs from lexical verbs in English grammar: negation, inversion, code, emphasis._ This presupposes that this is the complete list; there are 4, each is unique and identifiable, and they are the only things that distinguish lexical from auxiliary verbs. And then it gives names, but no descriptions.

Comment: Somehow unbeknownst to you, 'NICE' has "become popular". Most recent serious discussions of English auxiliaries do mention 'NICE' or some variant thereof. For example, Modality and the English Modals, Second Edition by F.R. Palmer has a subsection titled "the NICE properties" on page 201. See the contents: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=yMbKAgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=modality+and+the+english+modals&ots=tsbwIAVaXM&sig=9W4m_Cd_jlXuEy3w8A0LsXcy6dQ#v=onepage&q=modality%20and%20the%20english%20modals&f=false

Comment: McCawley has a [chapter (#8) on Auxiliary Verbs](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English/k6-C5AWWqjQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=auxiliary)

Comment: Why is that relevant?

Comment: Inversion happens in a wide range of environments, for example when a finite clause is preceded by a negative (or should I say negating) adjunct, or one using *only*: "Only if ... will she ...". Also conditional protases etc.

Answer (score 0):

*I sold the car, sold not I?

I sold the car, didn’t I?

*Sold I a car?"

Have I sold/Did I sell a car?

But

I have a car, haven’t I?

I have a car, don’t I?

Have I a car?

Have I had a car?

Did I have a car?

> is it really correct to say that the NICE properties are "the four syntactic characteristics that distinguish auxiliary verbs from lexical verbs in English grammar"?

There are no absolutes in English. Huddleston seems to have made a list of the usages of auxiliaries and then created "Rules" around these by noting patterns. As you will see from the site to which you link, there will be exceptions.

> (1) Do auxiliary verbs in non-finite clauses have the NICE properties?

In (1) Not having seen it, he had no clue. [Negation]. The question seems pointless. Whereas in

(i) I saw it, and (ii) "I have seen it" we have (i) SVO and (ii)S-Aux-pp-O, there is no subject and verb to be inverted:

in

(ii) *"I saw it not", and "I have not seen it", we have (ii) an error and (iia) S-Aux-{adv-pp}-O

but there is no subject - verb to invert:

(iii) "Having seen it, ..." and "Not having seen it, ...." We have [Adv]-Aux part- past p.-O

but we can also say

(iiia) "Having not seen it, he had no clue." but (iiib) *"Having seen not it, he had no clue." (Although "Having seen not it, but something else, he had no clue." is correct.)

> (3) He may have seen it and I may have. [Code]

The auxiliary is "may" - the second infinite "have" can be omitted.

> (4) ??They don't think he **has** seen it but he must **HAVE** seen it. [Emphasis]

**Must** is the auxiliary.

Comment: In (3), I know that _have_ can be omitted. But _have_ there is the only non-finite auxiliary. In (3) and (4), _may_ and _must_ are the only finite auxiliaries, so I've discussed the non-finite auxiliary _have_. So even if you're right about NEGATION, the non-finite auxiliaries still don't have the NICE properties.

Comment: In British English, I think _have_ has the NICE properties. A: _Have you a car?_ B: _No, I haven't._ A: _That's not true. You HAVE a car._ Whether to view this British _have_ as an auxiliary or as another piece of evidence that auxiliaries don't have the NICE properties is a different question, I think. // Also, I've edited the question to accommodate your answer.